# How can I stop a guest session created by startx command?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, guest-session, privileges, virtual-console

I was trying to use Ubuntu 12.4 with administrative privileges. So I typed the following commands in bash shell.

```
sudo -v
sudo su -
startx -- :2 vt8
```

I don't know what I have done. Now, I can login as a guest only at boot up.

When I try to login as a user, the login page refreshes and come back to the same page. When I log in as a guest, it won't allow me to access any of the user's file. I get this message:

```
you don't have the authority to access this folder.  
>It's not allowing to access any of the user's file.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you tell us what users (name and privileges) do you have (before and now)?

Comment: What happens if you enter Ctrl+Alt+F7? Does a login screen appear? Can you login there?

Comment: user name was user and privileges was administrative. I had ubuntu environment set up where i can compile and do lots of other things.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F7 doesn't do anything

Answer (score 3):

You updated your cached sudo credentials (no real effect), switched the user to yourself (again no effect), then started an X session on tty8, which had an effect :).

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> (not F7) to switch to the graphical display if you want to see it.

Starting the second X session caused a problem with your .Xauthority file. You can fix the problem by deleting it.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or F2, etc) to get to a terminal and login as yourself.

```
rm ~/.Xauthority
```